# Edit line colors in a matplotlib Axis object

Tags: matplotlib

I generated a plot with 7 curves and saved it as a Matplotlib Axis object. However, now I want to change the colors in each one of those curves. Since the curves take a while to generate, is it possible to change the colors of these curves from the Axis object itself?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.random.random(10)
y2 = np.random.random(10)


kwargs_1 = {
    'color': 'red',
    'linestyle': ':',
    'label': '1',
}

kwargs_2 = {
    'color': 'blue',
    'linestyle': '--',
    'label': '2',
}

ax.plot(x, y1, **kwargs_1)
ax.plot(x, y2, **kwargs_2)

pickle.dump(ax, open('axis_obj.pkl', 'wb'))

plt.clf()
plt.close()

ax_read = pickle.load(open('axis_obj.pkl', 'rb'))

fig = plt.figure()
ax_read.figure = fig
fig.axes.append(ax_read)
fig.add_axes(ax_read)

# and now I'm stuck on how to access the plot kwargs used earlier for this ax_read object
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, you must give an example of your code.

Comment: Hi @AlessandroPeca, I added some code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the colors by using this code:

```
# change the color of the plot lines:
ax.properties()['children'][0].set_color('green')
ax.properties()['children'][1].set_color('black')
```

Explanation: The `axes` object has the attribute `properties` which holds the children of the `axes` object. `children` is a list containing all objects which were drawn to the axis:

```
>>> ax.properties()['children']
    [
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f2edb896b70>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f2edb896ac8>,
 ...]
```

The first two elements are the plots which you have drawn to the axis.

Answer (score 2):

`ax.get_lines()` is a better way.

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: @JeremyCaney ax.properties() will get many irrelevant objects while ax.get_lines() only gets line objects.